# Is it possible to create an error log in java that extends to all classes?

Tags: java, error-log

Is it possible to create an error log in java that extends/works to all classes in a package?

So when I handle exceptions in various classes, I can simply log that error into one single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the numerous Java logging frameworks available, in particular:

- [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/)
- [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/)

Both of these allow you to customize (at config time and runtime) which statements to log, where to log them (the console, a single file, many files, files per error level) and how to format them.

Comment: Note that slf4j is a common _API_ where log4j is an _implementation_.  slf4j can be used with log4j.

Answer (score 2):

Check out logging frameworks like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) or [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)

Answer (score 0):

[Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) is *the* industry standard way of logging. You can great control over where log messages go, but the usual set up is to send everything to one file.

Comment: This is not necessarily true.  It was back in the 1.3 days.

Comment: What do you think is the "standard" now?

Comment: Code against slf4j, choose backend per project:  logback can do a lot, JDK-logging works across classloaders, log4j for legacy projects.